Much as we have Recursive Bernstein-Vazirani, can we construct Recursive Wordle?
Initially when I first saw an old question about using a quantum computer to solve Wordle, I had dismissed it as nothing but a cute gimmicky mashup.  But upon further consideration, the Bernstein-Vazirani algorithm solves Wordle with a single query, by preparing the uniform superposition of five registers over all twenty-six English-language characters/letters, querying the oracle, and closing the interference.  So, the question is actually pretty nice, as it helps to explain the meaning of an oracle and how the Bernstein-Vazirani algorithm could be instantiated in the real world.  It also "solves" a problem in a single query that classically takes me about three or four queries to the oracle (stored on the New York Times website I think.)
But the Bernstein-Vazirani paper also describes a recursive algorithm, that offers a superpolynomial speedup and gives tantalizing evidence of how powerful quantum computers could really be.  Recursive Bernstein-Vazirani is a bit mysterious and pretty hard for me to grok. However, quoting from @dabacon:

Oftentimes the recursive Bernstein-Vazirani problem is just passed over in a history of quantum computing and never discussed in much detail. This is a shame because it is a beautiful result and was the first really solid evidence that quantum computers might challenge the classical complexity of algorithms.

Aaronson also states:

Unfortunately, even to define the Recursive Fourier Sampling problem would take a longer digression than I feel is prudent. (If you think Simon's problem was artificial, you ain't seen nuthin'!)

To this end, then, can we modify Wordle to make a recursive version thereof, in a manner that feels natural and not so contrived?
Bernstein-Vazirani initially feels contrived, but Wordle is a pretty natural problem.  Recursive Bernstein-Vazirani seems even more unnatural, but can we modify the Wordle game to something only solvable with the recursive algorithm, while still keeping some of its charm and elegance?
